# MVC with EntityFramework model as stored procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, model

We have an Asp.net Web application with a normal Ado.NET Oracle connectivity.
The back end works completely on `stored procedures`. 
Now, our management has asked us to upgrade the entire application to MVC. 
The management has come up with some standards where they say we must use `EntityFramework model` and go with the same set of `stored procedures` without any change.

Here is my question. Each action in my application is running from `stored procedures` written in the `Oracle DB`. Is it possible for me to call the exact same `stored procedures` from `Entity framework` in Oracle. How can I achieve this?

The stored procedures does plenty of things in the back end like insert,update, select or all in most of the cases.

> I know entity framework needs an Entity model. If stored-procedures
>   will work, what will be the entity model. Is there any workaround for
>   this?

Answer (score 1):

Try out this [example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx) for using stored procedure with Entity Framework, maybe you need to understand the things in your project, whether to use entities or complex types as part of your stored procedures.

Comment: That was helpful. I will go through it in detail. I was pretty much confused on what will be the entity model. Because in tables the relations, table structure everything comes and you just need to call the methods. In stored procedures i was confused.